# Dynamic methds on JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a simple HTML tag engine in JavaScript. The idea is to use the tag name as the function name, yet the function does not have to be implemented in order to do that. Lets assume it lives within an object called `HTML`.

It should look something like this:

```
HTML.h1({class:"uberheadline"}, "Hello World");
HTML.div({id:"megabox"});
```

A very basic implementation I have so far is this:

```
function create_and_append_html_element(params) {
  var attributes = params.attr;
  var tag = params.tag;
  var target = params.target;
  var content = params.content;

  var element = document.createElement(tag);
  if (attributes) $(element).attr(attributes);
  if (content) $(element).html(content);
  if (target) $(target).append(element);
  return element;
}
```

In essence I'd like to run a function like this, only without having to specify the `tag` variable. Is it possible? If so, where's a good place to start looking for answers?

Comment: You're basically asking to overload the dot operator, which isn't possible in standard Javascript as far as I know. If there is some hacky way to do it, it's gonna be way worse than just defining the small set of acceptable tags somewhere.

Comment: A great HTML tag engine would also have to create valid HTML, which means you'd need a list of allowed attributes on different tags anyway. Then, using something like Triptych's solution should do the trick.

Comment: thats true, however this case shall not be limited to valid tags. Its up to the developer to chose the tags and attributes correctly. Predefining everything is what I'd like to avoid for the sake of automation and code consistency. The funnction does exist already within our perl code base, so people would like it to work the same way in JavaScript if anyhow possible.

Comment: Roman - as far as I know you'll have to define that whitelist, and will have to create small placeholder functions as I have in my example. It can probably be done more cleanly than my 5-minute hack but on the same order of complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write logic to infer the value of `tag` if it is not passed to your function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to make functions like `HTML.h1` which will call `create_and_append_html_element` internally with the `tag` property set automatically.

To do so, you can create such functions as follows:

```
// array of elements separated with space
$.each("h1 div".split(" "), function(i, tag) {
    // make the function available as HTML.h1, HTML.div, etc.
    HTML[tag] = function(attr, content) {
        return create_and_append_html_element({ tag:     tag  // pass tag through
                                                attr:    attr,
                                                content: content });
    };

});
```

I don't know the exact syntax and what the signature of those `HTML.h1` functions are (it looks like `(attr, content)`), but you can alter that of course.

Comment: thats correct. The syntax would go like this


     "HTML.<tag_name>(parameters, content);"


Yet I don't want to predefine a set of tags. In essence I'd need to know the name by which a non existent method is called and use that as a tag name.

Comment: @Roman Geber: Are you looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod? I believe it's only supported by Firefox, though.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call a method dynamically by it's string name you ca do the following:

```
HTML.h1({class:"uberheadline"}, "Hello World");
HTML.div({id:"megabox"});

var methodToCall = 'h1';

if(typeof(HTML[methodToCall]) === 'function') {
    HTML[methodToCall](); // run function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I was bored so I took a crack. The last line is where you were trying to get.

```
  // Using a tag whitelist
  var tags = [
     'div', 'b', 'a', 'i', 'link', 'script', 'p', 'em', 'span' // ... and so on
  ]

  // HTML constructor
  function _HTML() {
  }

  // Your magic create/append function
  function create_append(tagname, params) {
     params.target.append (document.createElement(tagname));
  };

  // Patch prototype with one closure per tag name in whitelist
  for (var i=0; i<tags.length; i++) {
     var tagname = tags[i];
     _HTML.prototype[tagname] = function(tagname) {
        return function (params) {
           return create_append(tagname, params);
        }
     }(tagname);
  }

  // Export user-accessible object
  var HTML = new _HTML;

  // Now you can do this!
  HTML.div({target:$('body')});
```

[Full jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hs3hx/7/).